# Hadoop Metrics Issue

Tags: hadoop2, ambari

I am provisioning `hadoop` cluster with `ambari` local repository. My ambari server is running in one machine and the cluster nodes are running on remote machines. I am successfully able to create the cluster.

[image: Ambari snapshot]

However I am not getting any metrics. Can you  suggest your i/ps  what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a proxy issue. See the instructions in [Ambari manual](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.2.1/bk_ambari_reference_guide/content/_how_to_set_up_an_internet_proxy_server_for_ambari.html). If so, fix is to set `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts` to list of your remote nodes and restart Ambari Server.